# Dynamic Data - Make Friendly Column Names in VB?

Tags: asp.net, vb.net, visual-studio-2010, linq-to-entities

How would I adapt the answer for [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3062866/dynamic-data-make-friendly-column-names)

for VB.NET instead of C#?

I've followed the guides linked, but haven't managed to figure it out. I'm using linq-to-entities and .net 4.0.

Answer (score 0):

Just the answer in VB.Net?

```
Imports System.ComponentModel
Imports System.ComponentModel.DataAnnotations

<MetadataType(GetType(MovieMetaData))>
Partial Public Class Movie


End Class

Public Class MovieMetaData

    <Required>
    Public Property Title As Object

    <Required>
    <StringLength(5)>
    Public Property Director As Object

    <DisplayName("Date Released")>
    <Required>
    Public Property DateReleased As Object

End Class
```

(not tested)

Comment: I'm not sure what to replace "MovieMetaData" and "Movie" with. The field I'm trying to modify has a column name of "status".

Comment: Ok.. I thought your question was to re-write the answer in VB.Net? So if this is not your question please update your question with accruate details. however based on your question the answer above is correct.